# OpenVPN management interface listens on a random port despite config

Tags: openvpn

I have a working point-to-point VPN connection between two machines, A and B.

I have the line in my openvpn config on A:

```
management tunnel 7505 management-pass.txt
```

When I start the daemon, it does not listen on port 7505, but just a random port. If I find the port using `ss -l` on A, I can connect to it (from either machine) and it asks for the password as configured. How can I make openvpn listen on a consistent port?

Using `OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` on A, and `OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` on B if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in OpenVPN 2.4+ https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/971